# Read-Only QT form

Tags: qt, widget, readonly

I am looking to make a QT form read-only, but NOT disabled. What I am trying to achieve is that the user is still able to use the controls on it, for example see what elements are there in a combo box, or scroll to the end of a list box, but should not be able to change the values of these components. Since the disabled form does not allow any interaction, and I did not find in the API anything related to make a form read-only I am wondering what possible solution are there for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose the approach to have a special method in my Form class which:

- makes the text edits read-only
- the combo/check/list, other controls disabled
- controls which allow navigation are enabled

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this would be to connect to the `currentIndexChanged` signal of the QComboBox in question and prevent it changing from what you want it to be. If this is something you want to do a lot, you may consider subclassing the QComboBox; but there's nothing that lets you do this in the default framework.

Comment: actually I'm planning to do this for an entire window with not only combo boxes on it... but any other components. Maybe I will need to subclass a lot of components. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: The combobox is surely the only one that's an issue for this though, as the 'disabled' state for most other widgets (ie, LineEdit..) will be sufficient for a read-only view.

Comment: nop, for example you cannot change the Tabs in a TabWidget either :(

Comment: but a TabWidget need not be disabled, it doesn't let the user edit anything anyway.